# Changing layer provider (datasource) from shapefile to PostgreSQL with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, postgresql, data-source

I have a QGIS project with several layers using shapefiles.
I want to change the datasource of each layer using a PostgreSQL table to replace the shapefile source.

I tried this code, but nothing changed in the layer:

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name() == "my_layer_name":
        provider = layer.dataProvider()
        uri = provider.uri()
        nw_uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        nw_uri.setDriver("postgres")
        nw_uri.setConnection(HOST, PORT, DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD)
        nw_uri.setDataSource(nw_sch, nw_tblname, "geom", aKeyColumn='id')
        provider.setDataSourceUri(nw_uri.uri())
        provider.reloadData()
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've found myself the answer. You have to use [`setDataSource()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsDataSourceUri.html#a7d4b63550162c9f0d4d4cafdd8caef6d) on the layer:

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name() == "my_layer_name":
        provider = layer.dataProvider()
        uri = provider.uri()
        nw_uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        nw_uri.setDriver("postgres")
        nw_uri.setConnection(HOST, PORT, DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD)
        nw_uri.setDataSource(nw_sch, nw_tblname, "geom", aKeyColumn='id')
        layer.setDataSource(nw_uri.uri(), layer.name, 'postgres')
```